# No suitable constructor found for Color(int,int,int,double)

Tags: java

I am trying to edit an image so that it has a "rainbow" edit to it. To do this, I simply want to fill in separate rows to fill the image in with the colors of a rainbow. However, if I were to do this, the colors would cover the image. So, I want to add transparency to my colors. However, when I try to do this I run into the error message as mentioned in the title. Here is my code:

```
 /**
 * This program takes a picutre, and places a special effect on it that colors it similar to how a rainbow would be.
 * 
 * @author Dylan Hubbs
 * @version 08/03/16
 */
import java.awt.*;    
class Rainbow
{
    Rainbow()
    {
    }

    public void rainbowEffect(Picture pictureObj)
    {
        int redValue = 0; int greenValue = 0; int blueValue = 0;
        Pixel rainbowTargetPixel = new Pixel(pictureObj, 0,0);               
        Color rainbowPixelColor = null;
        Color [] rainbowPalette = {new Color(255, 0, 0, .5), new Color(255, 200, 0, .5), Color(255, 255, 0, .5), Color(0, 255, 0, .5), Color(0, 0, 255, .5), new Color(138, 43, 226, .5), new Color(75, 0, 130, .5)};

        for(int y=0; y < pictureObj.getHeight(); y++)
        {
            for(int x = 0; x < pictureObj.getWidth(); x++)
            {
                rainbowTargetPixel = pictureObj.getPixel(x,y);                

                if(y >= 0 && y <= 50)
                rainbowTargetPixel.setColor(rainbowPalette[0]);
                if(y >= 51 && y <= 100)
                rainbowTargetPixel.setColor(rainbowPalette[1]);
                if(y >= 101 && y <= 150)
                rainbowTargetPixel.setColor(rainbowPalette[2]);
                if(y >= 151 && y <= 200)
                rainbowTargetPixel.setColor(rainbowPalette[3]);
                if(y >= 201 && y <= 250)
                rainbowTargetPixel.setColor(rainbowPalette[4]);
                if(y >= 251 && y <= 300)
                rainbowTargetPixel.setColor(rainbowPalette[5]);      
            }
        }

        pictureObj.explore();                                           
        pictureObj.write("RainbowWashingtonMonument.jpg");                 
        pictureObj.show();                                              
    }
}

public class RainbowTester
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Picture pictureObj = new Picture("washingtonmonument.jpg");
        pictureObj.explore();
        Rainbow rb = new Rainbow();

        rb.rainbowEffect(pictureObj);
    }
}
```

So, the error comes in at

> {new Color(255, 0, 0, .5)

And, I'm sure the error would continue on for the other colors in the array. This error does not happen when I try to add the floating value at the end of each method... However, I thought that I could add the floating number for transparency? Please help!

Comment: Read the API for Color -- don't guess

Comment: Hint: read the javadoc for the classes you are using: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html ... that contains a list of all the constructors of that class. Just assuming that a certain constructor exists ... doesn't make your wish true.

Comment: I read it before and that's how I found out about the transparency floating number (this is what made me think that):                                                                         Color(float r, float g, float b, float a)
Creates an sRGB color with the specified red, green, blue, and alpha values in the range (0.0 - 1.0).

Comment: @DylanHubbs: exactly, all fields are floats -- cast your ints to floats.

Answer (score 0):

Java cannot figure out which constructor to call. Since you are passing 0.5 for alpha, you probably want the one taking four `float`s:

```
new Color(1F, 0, 0, .5F)
```

Note the use of `1` in place of `255`, because this constructor takes values in range 0..1.

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/OpeQpn)

Constructor taking four `int`s is another possibility, in which case you need to pass `128` for the alpha parameter:

```
new Color(255, 0, 0, 128)
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/udsORq)

Comment: That makes sense as well. I'm going to use the other constructor and have 128 as the alpha. Thanks for the help though!

Comment: And sorry this is a separate question... When I add this, my colors are still not transparent, they still cover my image... Do you know why this is happening?

Comment: @DylanHubbs Because you are setting pixels into the image, replacing what was there before. If you place your image over something else, the "rainbow pixels" that you set would look semi-transparent. The pixels from the original image are gone, though.

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html

shows multiple constructors for Color.
One that may suit you:

> Color(int r, int g, int b, int a)

Instead of 0.5 (**double**), you could just enter 128 (**integer**).

Comment: Is .5 actually an int?

Comment: No, .5 is a double. That's what is causing the error. It should be swapped with 128, which is an integer.

Comment: Right, you just missed that in your answer :)

Comment: And sorry this is a separate question... When I add this, my colors are still not transparent, they still cover my image... Do you know why this is happening?

Comment: @DylanHubbs you may find this helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13425797/overlay-a-transparent-color-on-top-of-a-png-with-alpha-channel

Answer (score 0):

There are few constructors:

- `public Color(int r, int g, int b)`
- `public Color(int r, int g, int b, int a)`
- `public Color(int rgb)`
- `public Color(int rgba, boolean hasalpha)`
- `public Color(float r, float g, float b)`
- `public Color(float r, float g, float b, float a)`
- `public Color(ColorSpace cspace, float components[], float alpha)`

You may use

`public Color(int r, int g, int b, int a)` (Creates an sRGB color with the specified red, green, blue, and alpha values in the range (0 - 255).)

or

`public Color(float r, float g, float b, float a)` (Creates an sRGB color with the specified red, green, blue, and alpha values in the range (0.0 - 1.0).  The actual color used in rendering depends on finding the best match given the color space available for a particular output device.)