# Combining lwjgl textures into a texture atlas

Tags: java, lwjgl

A model that i'm importing has few textures images. I want to load them all and make a texture atlas. I'm trying to mess around with javas BufferedImage, but i dont event know how to convert lwjgl Texture class to BufferedImage... So how can i make the texture atlas from Texture classes? The result should also be in the Texture class.

Answer (score 0):

Despite this question being more than four months old, I'd like to answer it just for the sake of anyone else who needs help with the same issue, as I did. You should be able to get the ARGB bytes from the Slick texture and convert that into a BufferedImage, and from there you can just combine the BufferedImages into one ([like so](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2318020/merging-two-images)) and convert that back to a Texture.