# Get a BufferedImage output composed of several image layers

Tags: java

for my current work, I need to add images on top of other images at runtime. I already searched and I don't want to draw it on a Swing component, I use it in an external API. 
Ideally, I would like a library (or a java-native way) with which I can specify several images to "layer", and it would return me a `BufferedImage` (or any Image object by the way).

Comment: If you want a single image (`BufferedImage`) in return, then you need to **compose** your images. Or what do you mean by "on top"?

Comment: I mean, I'd like to have an image which is on top of the background image (like a photoshop layer, if you see what you mean), and using something I'd like to have an Image object which is the background image with the other image on top.

Comment: This may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2318020/merging-two-images

Comment: Thanks, works very well. Can I specify a position at which the image will the top image will be drawn, or have I to use same image sizes and transparency (like a mask) ?

Comment: Have a look at the documentation for method drawimage...

Comment: Oh ! I didn't even notice the x;y coordinates. You may add an answer so I can set the subjet to solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a single image (`BufferedImage`) in return, then you need to **compose** your images.
This answer may help you stackoverflow.com/questions/2318020/merging-two-images.
Have a look at the documentation for method `drawImage` to control position and scaling of any drawing through the `Graphics` object.