# How to crop images and stitch into single image?

Tags: android, image-processing

I am new to image processing. I am learning it. I am stuck on stitching images.
I read about boofCV and openCV. But, I guess they are for the advanced level. I really wanted to merge image with basic level as I have less knowledge.

There are 70% overlapping between to images.So, I need to cut 70% from second image and then merge.

So, kindly tell me how to proceed with it. Tell me the library to focus.

Thank you.

Comment: Check [Oracle's tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Merging two images](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2318020/merging-two-images)

Comment: Yup that's okay @SrikanthA But how i will cut the 70% of the second image?

Comment: Android is important.@haraldK please suggest me library on android platform

Comment: I have edited the tags @haraldK

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Graphics2D API could help you to crop. please rename the question subject.

```
    File file = new File("Image_name.jpg");
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
    BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(fis);
    int width = image.getWidth();
    int height = image.getHeight();
```

using this width, you can crop the image using Graphics2D API - draw Image method - [Graphics2D](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics2D.html#drawImage(java.awt.image.BufferedImage,%20java.awt.image.BufferedImageOp,%20int,%20int))

By passing right value for x, y to draw image method, you can get your desired crop.

Comment: Neither ImageIO or Java2D API is available on Android, so this won't work.

Comment: Question was intially tagged to java as well, Considering that - the answer was provided