# how to add transparent alpha channel back to png image in java?

Tags: java, image, png, alpha, java-2d

I am trying to attach the transparent alpha channel to png image in java. Image should not be changed after merging of alpha channel.
In short,

1. I have png image of dimension p X q
2. I have alpha channel(transparent) of 100% transparency and of size p X q
3. Above both images(1 and 2) should be merged and image 1 should remain as it is without any effect of alpha channel...
   Please help me out...

Comment: What have you tried? Also, how do you merge the alpha channel with 100% transparency without affecting the image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the alpha channel in the first image according to the transparency information in the second image. Something like this: [Set BufferedImage alpha mask in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/221830/set-bufferedimage-alpha-mask-in-java)

If you don't want to have any changes in the first image, then you can create a copy/clone of it and work with this copy. Here's how to create a copy of a BufferedImage: [How do you clone a BufferedImage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3514158/how-do-you-clone-a-bufferedimage)

Comment: Is there a way to set a single alpha parameter -i.e. making the mask a single constant vector?. I tried the cited solution though i figured if there is any efficient solution for this simpler case.......