# Applying alpha paths to images in java

Tags: java, alpha, javax.imageio, twelvemonkeys

I want to apply the alpha mask which is there in the image data. i have
images of different formats namely tiffs,PSD PNGand jpeg.I am
reading them as bufferedimage, and want to use the Twelvemonkeys lib
to get the alpha paths configured in the images, and apply the transperency accordingly. But  i can't find
the relevant functions. Please help.

```
ImageInputStream stream = ImageIO.createImageInputStream(new File(c:/img.psd);
BufferedImage image = Paths.readClipped(stream);
image.getcoclormodel().hasAlpha(); 

for(i < image.getwidth()) {
   for(j < image.getHeight()) {
       pixels = image.getRGB(i, j, width, height, null, 0, width);
       Color col = new Color(pixels[pixelIndex]);
       int p = col.getAlpha() 
       image.setRGB(i, j, width, height, p, 0, width)
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, interesting, perhapse this might be of interest https://stackoverflow.com/questions/221830/set-bufferedimage-alpha-mask-in-java

Comment: I want the alpha channels which are configured in the photoshop images and other tiff images also, then I want to apply them to get the new bufferedimage

Answer (score 0):

Using the `Paths.readClipped(...)` method will read both the image data and the Photoshop clipping path resource, and apply the clipping path to the image. In other words, the resulting `BufferedImage` will contain transparency according to the path.

If you prefer to read the path and image separately, you could use the `readPath(...)` and `applyClippingPath(...)` methods of the `Paths` utility class:

```
try (ImageInputStream stream = ImageIO.createImageInputStream(new File("image_with_path.jpg")) {
    Shape clip = Paths.readPath(stream);
    stream.seek(0);
    BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(stream);

    if (clip != null) {
        image = Paths.applyClippingPath(clip, image);
    }

    // Do something with the clipped image...
}
```

The above code basically does the same thing as `readClipped(...)` but allows you to inspect and modify each step.

PS: Note that the methods in `Paths` is for use only with images containing Photoshop Resource Blocks with ClippingPath resources (resource id `0x07d0`). The alpha channel of the image will always be present. For PSD and TIFF files containing multiple alpha channels (aka "transparency masks"), there is currently no way to access the extra alpha channels.